# How to repeat text formatting settings in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, formatting

I have a bunch of text point objects and I'd like to select a subset of them and change their font size (for example). They might be in different groups so I can't select them all at once, so I select a few change the font size, then I select a few more, and change the font size manually again.

I'm wondering if there is a repeat last action button. I know about `Cmd+D` but it doesn't work for applying text styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **Character** and **Paragraph Styles**. This is what they are for.

`Window > Type > Character Styles` and `Window > Type > Paragraph Styles`.

Set type how you want it to look and highlight it. Then click the `New` icon on the bottom of the appropriate style panel. When you want to apply the same text formatting, highlight the text, and click the style you created.

Character Styles define individual, inline, pieces of text. Paragraph Styles apply to entire paragraphs of text.

[**You can learn more here via Adobe Help.**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS9D351498-DAAC-4be1-B4B8-2B6C72FF6CEDa.html)

Comment: I don't think that is the answer Nachocab and I were looking for. We know that there are Para and Character styles, but how to set the same style for many text parts??

Comment: Select the text - however much of it there is -  or select the text frames, and click the style.